# Получить массив сущностей из jsonb объекта

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jpa

Мой запрос, который по моему мнению должен возвращать список сущностей
для дальнейшей фильтрации по `DocumentType`

```
@Repository
public interface SchematronRepository extends JpaRepository<SchematronEntity, String>{
    @Query(value = "select \"SCHEMATRONS\" from \"SEMD\".\"SEMD_VALIDATION_SCHEMA\" where \"IMPLEMENTATION_MANUAL_OID\" = :oid", nativeQuery = true)
    ArrayList<SchematronJson> getContentByImplementationManualOid(String oid);
}
```

Что я получаю в итоге

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [DocumentValidator.Domain.SchematronJson]
```

Моя сущность, которую я хочу видеть как результат запроса

```
public class SchematronJson implements Serializable {
    public SchematronJson(String Name, String Content, int DocumentType){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Content = Content;
        this.DocumentType = DocumentType;
    }
    private String Name;
    private String Content;
    private int DocumentType;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return Content;
    }

    public int getDocumentType() {
        return DocumentType;
    }

}
```

То что хранится в колонке `SCHEMATRONS` имеет вид

```
[
   {
      "Name" : "name1",
      "Content" : "content1",
      "DocumentType" : 1
   },
   {
      "Name" : "name2",
      "Content" : "content2",
      "DocumentType" : 2
   }
]
```

Я новичок в Java, не совсем понимаю как маппить результат запроса в сущность сразу.
Подскажите пожалуйста что я должен сделать чтобы это работало?

Comment: Его не маппить нужно а конвертировать.

Comment: @RomanC Очень дельное замечание, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-ж, мне удалось решить эту проблему таким образом.

Класс `SchematronJson` теперь выглядит так.

```
public class SchematronJson implements Serializable {
public SchematronJson(){ }
private String Name;
private String Content;
private int DocumentType;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String Name){
    this.Name = Name;
}
public String getContent() {
    return Content;
}
public void setContent(String Content){
    this.Content = Content;
}
public int getDocumentType() {
    return DocumentType;
}
public void setDocumentType(String DocumentType){
    this.DocumentType = Integer.parseInt(DocumentType);
}
```

Я поменял в нем конструктор и добавил сеттеры.

Так же изменениям подвергся запрос

```
public String getByImplementationManualOid(String implementationManualOid, String documentType) {
    String sql = "select \"SCHEMATRONS\" from \"SEMD\".\"SEMD_VALIDATION_SCHEMA\" where \"IMPLEMENTATION_MANUAL_OID\" = ?";
    var schematrons = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,(rs, rowNum) -> {
        String json = rs.getString("SCHEMATRONS");
        JsonNode jsonNode;
        try {
            jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        var schList = new ArrayList<SchematronJson>();
        jsonNode.forEach(x -> {
            var schematron = new SchematronJson();
            schematron.setName(x.get("Name").asText());
            schematron.setContent(x.get("Content").asText());
            schematron.setDocumentType(x.get("DocumentType").asText());
            schList.add(schematron);
        });
        return schList.stream().filter(x -> x.getDocumentType() == Integer.parseInt(documentType)).findFirst().orElse(new SchematronJson());
    }, implementationManualOid);

    return schematrons.stream().findFirst().get().getContent();
}
```